# The ion-slide-box's pager point will disappears when when scrolling ion-content up and down

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

As the title says, the ion-slide-box's pager point will  disappears when when scrolling ion-content up and down on device.

Anyone know what's happening?  how to fix this problem?